# NetBeans 6.9.1 with Websphere 6.1

Tags: netbeans-6.9, websphere-6.1

I'm trying to setup a local websphere 6.1 server w/ netbeans 6.9.1.  I installed the websphere application server and the server plug-in.  But I'm not seeing it in netbeans when I bring up the add servers in the services tab.

I am no expert in installation - but it appears like it installed correctly.  I checked out the docs and it's ok.

Any leads, tips, hints, guide for dummies would be appreciated :)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The server plugin is not supported anymore for new Netbeans versions.